# How to use the options pattern with these services in Startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#recommendations) it is explained how to configure a service in Startup.ConfigureServices() but how do you use the options pattern with services that use extensions of the IServiceCollection like services.[AddHttpClient()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) or services.[AddDbContext()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-5.0), etc.

For example the current code has to be changed to use the options pattern:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(dbContextOptionsBuilder =>
      dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(myOptionsInstance.AString));
```

Example of the options pattern working with DI:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie();

    services.AddOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(
                        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .Configure<IMyService>((options, myService) =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = myService.GetLoginPath();
        });

    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to provide configuration values when adding services?

Comment: @NoahStahl yes, but not the regular services like services.AddSingleton<IXService, XService>(); . The question is about those services that expose special extension methods to be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Within `ConfigureServices` you can [bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration) an options class instance to values in Startup's constructor-injected `IConfiguration`. For example:

```
var myOptions = Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig").Get<MyOptions>();
```

Assuming this binds successfully, `myOptions` should have the current configuration values which can be provided as service paramters.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(dbContextOptionsBuilder =>
      dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(myOptions.AString));
```

Comment: I was more interested in the services.AddOptions().Configure() way because MyOptions is handled by DI.

Comment: That's only if you need an OptionsBuilder. If you're just trying to get the config values for initialization, binding an instance seems simple enough to me.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using something like that binding. Is it not possible to use the AddOptions().Configure() with these ICollectionServices extensions?

Comment: Not sure, but curious why the desire for this specific approach?

Comment: Options pattern with DI